# DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for extent report in log used by log4j

Tags: maven, log4j, report, extent

2020-06-05 09:13:30 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:30 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:30 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:30 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/index.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "head.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("head_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("head.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "head.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/head.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "nav.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("nav_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("nav.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "nav.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/nav.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "test-view/test-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "test-view/test-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/test-view/test-view.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view-charts_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/test-view/test-view-charts.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "test-view/bdd.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/bdd_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("test-view/bdd.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "test-view/bdd.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/test-view/bdd.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - "test-view/bdd.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) cached copy not yet stale; using cached.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - "test-view/bdd.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) cached copy not yet stale; using cached.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "category-view/category-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("category-view/category-view_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("category-view/category-view.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "category-view/category-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/category-view/category-view.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "author-view/author-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("author-view/author-view_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("author-view/author-view.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "author-view/author-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/author-view/author-view.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "exception-view/exception-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("exception-view/exception-view_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("exception-view/exception-view.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "exception-view/exception-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/exception-view/exception-view.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("dashboard-view/dashboard-view_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/sadakarp/.m2/repository/E1SmapiUiAutomation/E1SmapiUiAutomation/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/E1SmapiUiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report/dashboard-view/dashboard-view.ftl"
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("logs-view/testrunner-logs-view_en.ftl"): Not found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"): Found
2020-06-05 09:13:31 DEBUG cache:45 - Loading template for "logs-view/testrunner-logs-view.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) fr

Answer (score 0):

so for this issue I just added a line in my log4j.properties and this time I am getting no error
line added:log4j.logger.freemarker.cache = INFO, CONSOLE